# Is Intel VT-d at all useful if direct device attachement is not required?

Tags: virtualization, vt-d

It seems that one disadvantage of Intel i3 processors versus their more capable i5 and i7 brothers is the consistent lack of [VT-d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#I.2FO_MMU_virtualization_.28AMD-Vi_and_VT-d.29) support. I understand the basics of IOMMU hardware and how it would benefit people that want their virtual machines to access their hardware directly.

What I am wondering is whether VT-d has any *other* uses besides that. Could it benefit in *any* way a user that is content letting their host OS handle the hardware? For example, is there any hypervisor that uses VT-d e.g. to speed-up paravirtualized devices somehow? Or, say, to run nested guests?

*Note: I am not asking for either speculation or shopping advice - just* concrete *information, if possible...*

Comment: The K series core i5 and i7 lack this as well, for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not any benefit. VT-d (IOMMU) is just re-mapping of the device, it's pretty simple, actually re-mapped HW becomes unbinded and then host OS doesn't know about this device.

*OT: For everybody who's checking his CPU, this is useful: http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced?VTD=true  ... and beware of C1 stepping!*

Comment: This does indeed seem to be the answer from what I have been able to gather...